# MongoDB very slow to count even tho indexed

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization

I am wondering why my count query is very slow even tho its indexed. The explain looks like:

```
{
    "explainVersion": "1",
    "queryPlanner": {
        "namespace": "xxx.yyy",
        "indexFilterSet": False,
        "parsedQuery": {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "_cls": {
                        "$eq": "ABC"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "organisationId": {
                        "$eq": ObjectId("...")
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached": False,
        "maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached": False,
        "maxScansToExplodeReached": False,
        "winningPlan": {
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "inputStage": {
                "stage": "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern": {
                    "_cls": 1,
                    "organisationId": 1
                },
                "indexName": "_cls_1_organisationId_1",
                "isMultiKey": False,
                "multiKeyPaths": {
                    "_cls": [],
                    "organisationId": []
                },
                "isUnique": False,
                "isSparse": False,
                "isPartial": False,
                "indexVersion": 2,
                "direction": "forward",
                "indexBounds": {
                    "_cls": [
                        "["ABC", "ABC"]"
                    ],
                    "organisationId": [
                        "[ObjectId("..."), ObjectId("...")]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
...
"executionStats": {
    "executionSuccess": True,
    "nReturned": 623707,
    "executionTimeMillis": 13965,
    "totalKeysExamined": 623707,
    "totalDocsExamined": 623707,
    "executionStages": {
        "stage": "FETCH",
        "nReturned": 623707,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 11073,
        "works": 623708,
        "advanced": 623707,
        "needTime": 0,
        "needYield": 0,
        "saveState": 814,
        "restoreState": 814,
        "isEOF": 1,
        "docsExamined": 623707,
        "alreadyHasObj": 0,
        "inputStage": {
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
            "nReturned": 623707,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 6393,
            "works": 623708,
            "advanced": 623707,
            "needTime": 0,
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 814,
            "restoreState": 814,
            "isEOF": 1,
            "keyPattern": {
                "_cls": 1,
                "organisationId": 1
            },
            "indexName": "_cls_1_organisationId_1",
            "isMultiKey": False,
            "multiKeyPaths": {
                "_cls": [],
                "organisationId": []
            },
            "isUnique": False,
            "isSparse": False,
            "isPartial": False,
            "indexVersion": 2,
            "direction": "forward",
            "indexBounds": {
                "_cls": [
                    "["ABC", "ABC"]"
                ],
                "organisationId": [
                    "[ObjectId("..."), ObjectId("...")]"
                ]
            },
            "keysExamined": 623707,
            "seeks": 1,
            "dupsTested": 0,
            "dupsDropped": 0
        }
    },
}
```

It looks like from the execution stats `nReturned==totalKeysExamined==totalDocsExamined` so meaning its direct from index, with 600k records isit supposed to be slow ~5s?

Comment: Is your disk health good?

Comment: I'd report it to jira.mongodb.org. There are number of tickets related to count optimisation where covered queries do not trigger COUNT_SCANS and do FETCH instead, e.g. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17266